# Thermistor value correct on Uno backwards on Nano

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

EDIT: upon further investigation: I found out that if I wired it Thermistor > resistor > GND values go one direction. If I wired it Thermistor > Resistor > 5v, it goes the other direction. So my new question: Which way is correct? One sketch assumes it works one way, and one the other.

I have some Thermistors from [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087YI1KW). I have an Arduino Nano and an Arduino Uno, both set up identically with pictures of the wiring below. On the sketch below, when I heat up the thermistor the value increases on the Uno and decreases on the Nano.

```
// which analog pin to connect
#define THERMISTORPIN A0
// resistance at 25 degrees C
#define THERMISTORNOMINAL 10000
// temp. for nominal resistance (almost always 25 C)
#define TEMPERATURENOMINAL 25
// how many samples to take and average, more takes longer
// but is more 'smooth'
#define NUMSAMPLES 5
// The beta coefficient of the thermistor (usually 3000-4000)
#define BCOEFFICIENT 3950
// the value of the 'other' resistor
#define SERIESRESISTOR 9800

int samples[NUMSAMPLES];

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  uint8_t i;
  float average;

  // take N samples in a row, with a slight delay
  for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
       samples[i] = analogRead(THERMISTORPIN);
   delay(10);
  }

  // average all the samples out
  average = 0;
  for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
     average += samples[i];
  }
  average /= NUMSAMPLES;

  Serial.print("Average analog reading ");
  Serial.println(average);

  // convert the value to resistance
  average = 1023 / average - 1;
  average = SERIESRESISTOR / average;
  Serial.print("Thermistor resistance ");
  Serial.println(average);

  float steinhart;
  steinhart = average / THERMISTORNOMINAL;     // (R/Ro)
  steinhart = log(steinhart);                  // ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT;                   // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15); // + (1/To)
  steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart;                 // Invert
  steinhart -= 273.15;                         // convert to C

  Serial.print("Temperature ");
  Serial.print(steinhart);
  Serial.println(" *C");
  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);
}
```

On the sketch below, the Uno is backwards and the Nano is correct. I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing, but I sure can't find it. Any suggestions?

```
#include <math.h>

double Thermistor(int RawADC) {
 double Temp;
 Temp = log(10000.0*((1024.0/RawADC-1)));
 Temp = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp ))* Temp );
 Temp = Temp - 273.15;
 Temp = (Temp * 9.0)/ 5.0 + 32.0;
 return Temp;
}

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int val;
  double temp;
  val=analogRead(7);
  temp=Thermistor(val);
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" F");
  delay(1000);
}
```

[Nano Wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ8Fs.jpg)

[Uno Wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIM29.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "correct" way. The thermistor and the resistor combine to make a voltage divider. Whether the thermistor is connected to +5V (AKA R1) or to GND (AKA R2) determines the formula to use to calculate the resistance.

The general form is:

```
          R2
Vout = ------- x Vin
       R1 + R2
```

To solve for R2 (thermistor connected to GND) you re-arrange to:

```
                 1
R2 = R1 x --------------
          (Vin/Vout) - 1
```

To solve for R1 (thermistor connected to +5V) it's:

```
     R2 x Vin
R1 = -------- - R2
       Vout
```

Vin, of course, is 5V, and Vout is a voltage you calculate from the analog reading on the Arduino.

Once you have the resistance you can then calculate the temperature. That part doesn't change regardless of the orientation of the thermistor.